# Преобразование типов "10101"->B10101

Tags: c++, arduino

Имеется массив:

```
byte customChar[8] = {
    B00000,
    B00000,
    B00000,
    B00000,
    B00000,
    B00000,
    B00000,
    B00000
};
```

В одной из функций я собираю строку вида `"10101"`. Есть ли функция или способ для преобразования этой строки к виду `B10101` для добавления как элемент к массиву `customChar`?

Comment: Нужно преобразовать строку "10101" в число b10101? Можно попробовать `stoi`, например: `byte b = (byte) std::stoi("10101", nullptr, 2);`

Comment: Значение вида `B10101` это какое-то расширение arduino, судя по всему. В рантайме никаких таких литералов нет, поэтому преобразование строки именно в число вида `b10101` для добавления в массив выглядит бессмысленным. Да и само добавление в массив такого вида в рантайме не является возможным. Размер массива фиксирован на этапе компиляции, можно лишь менять имеющиеся значения.

Comment: @älёxölüt, так мне и не надо добавлять, а лишь изменить определённый элемент массива (который указан выше), то есть был элемент B00000-> при работе функции получили строку "10001"-> изменили элемент массива на значение B10001

Comment: @gil9red, выдаёт ошибки 'stoi' is not member of 'std' и 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Чтобы `stoi` был, нужно иметь поддержку C++11. Она имеется в вашем компиляторе? Либо можно воспользоваться `strtol`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы преобразовать число, заданное строкой, в конкретное числовое значение можно использовать функции типа `std::stoi` или [`std::strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/), где дополнительно нужно указать систему счисления, в текущем случае, это `2`. Первая функция требует наличия поддержки стандарта C++11, вторая будет работать и без оного:

```
#include <cstdlib>

byte value = static_cast<byte>(std::strtol("10001", NULL, 2));
```

После преобразования можно записать значение в требуемую ячейку массива:

```
customChar[index] = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef unsigned char bin_t;

void binToString(bin_t number, char *result)
{
   result[0] = 'B';
   for( bin_t n = sizeof(bin_t); n > 0; --n) {
      result[sizeof(bin_t) - n + 1] = (number & (1 << (n - 1))) ? '1' : '0';
   }
   result[sizeof(bin_t) + 1] = 0;
}

...

char str[sizeof(bin_t)+2];
bin_t number = 0b0101001;
binToString(number, str);
std::cout << str;
```